# Jackson update part of object

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-modules

This is what I am trying to do. lets say I have 2 json inputs.

First

```
{"testArr":[{"name":"name1"},{"name":"name2"}]}
```

Second

```
{"testArr":[{"name":"name1Changed"}]}
```

And I have classes

```
class test{
 public String name;
}

class runner{
  public ArrayList<test> testArr;
  public String firstJson;
  public String secondJson;

  public void runProj(){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //This one is correct works just fine
    testArr = mapper.readValue(firstJson, ITBTeam.class);

    //Now I want to update just value of first element of array and 
    //tryed to use this function but this one will trim my array
     mapper.readerForUpdating(testArr).readValue(secondJson);
  }

}
```

So after this one I am getting

```
{"testArr":[{"name":"name1Changed"}]}
```

where I want to get

```
{"testArr":[{"name":"name1Changed"},{"name":"name2"}]}
```

Please let me know if I am missing something from Jackson or there are no such functionality and I would need to write my own.

Since there are no straight conversation to do what i wanted here is what i wrote for json nodes to do the same thing. Two functions to merger/overwrite nodes and merge/overwriteArray. This works by passing 2 json Nodes hope that will help if anyone are looking for similar things

```
 public static JsonNode mergeNode(JsonNode mainNode, JsonNode updateNode) {
    Iterator<String> fieldNames = updateNode.fieldNames();
    while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {

        String fieldName = fieldNames.next();
        JsonNode jsonNode = mainNode.get(fieldName);
        // if field exists and is an embedded object
        if (null != jsonNode && (jsonNode.isObject())) {
            mergeNode(jsonNode, updateNode.get(fieldName));
            // if field exists and is an embedded array
        } else if (null != jsonNode && (jsonNode.isArray())) {
            mergeArray(jsonNode, updateNode.get(fieldName));
        } else {
            // Overwrite field node               
            ((ObjectNode) mainNode).set(fieldName, updateNode.get(fieldName));
        }
    }
    return mainNode;
}

public static void mergeArray(JsonNode mainNode, JsonNode updateNode) {
    //Loops over array and adds items if they dont exist 
    //or updates existing value if it is not an object
    for (int i = 0; i < updateNode.size(); i++) {
        JsonNode jsonNode = mainNode.get(i);
        if (null != jsonNode && jsonNode.isObject()) {
            mergeNode(jsonNode, updateNode.get(i));
        } else if (null != jsonNode && (jsonNode.isArray())) {
            mergeArray(jsonNode, updateNode.get(i));
        } else if (null == jsonNode) {
            ((ArrayNode) mainNode).add(updateNode.get(i));
        } else {
            ((ArrayNode) mainNode).set(i, updateNode.get(i));
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: No such fuctionality in Jackson; and even [this project](https://github.com/fge/json-patch) won't help, given that RFC 6902 would remove your second array element, and RFC 7386 would unconditionally replace all of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to read both document as `JsonNode`s, then traverse and update first document using logic you have in mind. Unfortunately there are many possible ways in which one might want to merge -- for example, in case of JSON arrays, should one or both be chosen; or should they be concatened; or should the entries be overridden by index (which is what you want) -- so Jackson does not have functionality for such processing.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can make use of JSON-Patch https://github.com/fge/json-patch to merge the two JSON object/node

```
    // With Jackson
    final JsonMergePatch patch = mapper.readValue(in, JsonMergePatch.class);
    // With a JsonNode
    final JsonMergePatch patch = JsonMergePatch.fromJson(node);

    // orig is also a JsonNode
    final JsonNode patched = patch.apply(orig);
```